# Можно ли как-нибудь сделать проверку на контент?

Tags: css

Я хочу сделать небольшие события в Discord. Если человек напишет сообщение "red", текст окрасится в красный. Это возможно на CSS или только на JS?

```
.messageContent-2t3eCI a[content="red"] {
    color: red;
}
```

Выше приведённый код - неработает

(С CSS у меня туго)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему можно решить только с помощью JS